# How to access a hsqldb DB with JDBC tools?

Tags: java, sql, database, jdbc, hsqldb

I have a hsqldb file database.
Therefore a folder contains:

```
hsqldb.script
hsqldb.properties
hsqldb.log
hsqldb.lck
hsqldb.tmp
```

When I open the script, I can see that SQL tables and INSERTs are present.
How can I use JDBC tools like squirrel to inspect the tables like a real database?

I tried connecting using `jdbc:hsqldb:file:C:\path\to\my\data\hsqldb` while the application is running that uses this DB.

I could connect, but all I could see are the initial `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` tables.
What am I missing here? Where is the data that I can see clearly in the .script, but not with an JDBC tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .lck and .tmp files indicate that the database was not shutdown prior to last connection close. Use the SHUTDOWN command to close the database.